# MVC4 - nav dropdown menu

Tags: css, dropdown

When the mouse hover the [Automotive], always the submenu items displayed beside each others [Create Auction][Display all auctions]; I need to display it as a list.

Please advise me :

HTML Code:(Create the menu)

```
  <div id="nav">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                            @foreach (string category in ViewBag.Categories)
                            {
                              <li>@Html.ActionLink(category,"Index","Auction",new{category},null)
                              @if (category== "Automotive")
                              {
                                <ul>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Auction", "Create", "Auction")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Display all auctions", "Auctions", "Auction")</li>
                                </ul>
                              }
                              </li>
                            }

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS Code:
       ----------------------------------------------------------------
       I added that code:

```
   #menu ul {
       display: none;
      position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
   }

   #menu li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
   }
   -----------------------------------------------------------
   ul#menu {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
   }

   ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
   }

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
```

}

says all li under #menu must be displayed inline.

You should add some specifics for submenu item like

```
ul#menu li ul li {
   display: block;
}
```

Then if you want to position your submenu below the corresponding item you must set the position of the item to relative and then position the submenu with position absolute.

so

```
ul#menu li {
     position:relative
}

ul#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That is great. Thank you. but - Menu Dropdown Showing in wrong spot . always under [Contact], any advise.

Comment: can you add a screenshot ? Im not sure to understand the "always under [Contact]" part

Comment: Kindly, find the screenshot in the question under the original image

Comment: could you try to add "right: 0;" to #menu ul directive ? ( #menu ul { ... right:0; ... }

Comment: I changed the position to relative :                                                             but the submenu push the content of the page to down. how can I avoid that.

Comment: just edited my answer i think this should work, if not could you had the generated html to you answer ? So i could try to reproduce more precisely.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, That is fine. Appreciate your support and your help.  :)

Comment: glad to help ! :D